# Using PL/SQL to develop relationship among two tables?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am new to the PL/SQL language and I am working on a problem and was looking for advice to the right direction to go. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have an Employee table and a Building table.
The Employee table consists of Employee_ID, Last_Name, First_Name, and Job(F/P) full or part time.
The Building table consists of Employee_ID and Building_location.(This is the location where the employee works from) either a home or office.

I want the user to type in the last_name from user input. As a result I am looking for the information from the employee: Employee Name, Job (full or part employee) and the building_location. For example, I want my output to look something like this if the user typed in Johnson:

```
Employee Name     Job Position     Building Location
====================================================
Andre Johnson      Part Time        Home Office
Nick Johnson       Full Time        Downtown Office
```

If a user types in any string I want to list all Employees who work for the company.  But if the name is on the Employee table like 'Johnson' is then it only displays Johnson.  Would I need to add in another SELECT clause?

At this point I put together some code that checks if the employee works for the company or not.  I am looking to build from this.

```
ACCEPT p_1 PROMPT 'Please enter the last name of the employee:'

DECLARE
v_name       employee.last_name%TYPE := '&p_1';
v_lname      employee.last_name%TYPE;
v_fname      employee.first_name%TYPE;
v_jobpos    employee.job%TYPE;
v_buildtype  building.building_type%TYPE;
v_count      NUMBER;

BEGIN
  SELECT    COUNT(*)
  INTO  v_count
  FROM  employee
  WHERE UPPER(last_name) = UPPER(v_name);

  IF v_count = 0 THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EMPLOYEE NAME        Job Position        Building Location');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('----------------------------------------------------'  );
        for i in (select * from employee order by last_name) loop
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i.last_name || ', ' || i.first_name)
 end loop;

ELSE
    for i in (select * from employee order by last_name) loop
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i.last_name || ', ' || i.first_name);

    end loop; 

END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a building_id column in the employee table rather than an employee_id column in the building table?

Comment: My tables are linked together from the Employee_ID @David Aldridge

Comment: One building per employee?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. The simplest way might be like this:

```
    ...
    IF v_count = 0 THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_name || ' Does not work here.');
        /* New code starts here! */
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Employees are:');
        for r in (select * from employees) loop
            dbms_output.put_line(r.last_name||', '||r.first_name);
        end loop;
        /* New code ends here! */
    ELSE
      ...
    end if;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, so I would have to change my IF statement then correct?

Comment: @DaBulls33: The `IF v_count=0 then` block wouldn't change, only your `ELSE` block.

Comment: Couldn't I leave the IF to what I previously had?

Comment: @DaBulls33: Yes, you can. I've added comments to my answer to make it clearer where my changes begin and end.

Comment: I seem to be having an error in my for loop.  I edited my original code around a little bit and it will not compile.  Any ideas?

Comment: the error report says ORA-06550: line 19, column 18: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following: (then lists different options)... Then ORA-06550: line 20, column 9:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DBMS_OUTPUT" when expecting one of the following: (lists different options)...The symbol "having" was substituted for "DBMS_OUTPUT" to continue.
ORA-06550: line 20, column 65:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:..........*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: @DaBulls33: My bad, I think the query should have in brackets. I've updated the code.

Comment: I updated my code above.  I was wondering  now how to go about adding the job position and the building location into the output.  This would all be included in the loop correct?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29684/discussion-between-dabulls33-and-frustratedwithformsdesigner)